# Returning HTML from ASP.NET MVC Extension function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. My app is displaying values from the model in my view like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ToMeasure<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string measurement = "sf")
{
  if (measurement == "m2")
    measurement = "m<sup>2</sup>";
  return System.Web.Mvc.Html.ValueExtensions.ValueFor(html, expression, "{0:N0} " + measurement);
}
```

Sometimes, `measurement` will represent square feet. Other times, it will represent square meters. When its square meters, I want to user the HTML `sup` tag. Unfortunately, right  now, it renders as a literal `m<sup>2</sup>` instead of as an actual superscript. How do I tell MVC to use a superscript instead of the literal?

Thanks!

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana can you please provide an example? I've never done that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to build the html elements you want to return

```
public static MvcHtmlString ToMeasure<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string measurement = "sf")
{
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    html.Append(ValueExtensions.ValueFor(helper, expression, "{0:N0}"));

    // or html.Append(helper.ValueFor(expression, "{0:N0}"));

    if (measurement == "m2")
    {
        html.Append("m");
        TagBuilder sup = new TagBuilder("sup");
        sup.InnerHtml = "2";
        html.Append(sup.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        html.Append(measurement);
    }
    // Optionally you might want to wrap it all in another element?
    TagBuilder span = new TagBuilder("span");
    span.InnerHtml = html.ToString();

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(span.ToString());
}
```

Side note: I suggest you could make this a bit more robust by having a `Enum` to specify the measurement type, and and passing that to the helper

Edit

In the view use it as

```
@Html.ToMeasure(m => m.yourProperty, "m2");
```

and assuming the value of `yourProperty` is 100, it generates the following output

```
<span>100m<sup>2</sup></span>
```

Comment: How do you call it from the view then? Currently, I have `@Html.ToMeasure(model => model.Size)` and its rendering as `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper`1[MyApp.MyProject.Models.MyViewModel]`

Comment: I have just tested it using `@Html.ToMeasure(m => m.myProperty, "m2");` and it works fine. Have you included the relevant assembly in the view? Are you sure you have copied the code exactly?